# NativeScript - Module 'ui/sidedrawer' not found for element 'Sidedrawer'

Tags: javascript, android, xml, typescript, nativescript

So I am creating a simple side-drawer menu for my application in NativeScript following this [tutorial](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/a-deep-dive-into-telerik-ui-for-nativescripts-sidedrawer).
I'm able to make it work for any given single page using the following code.

**starting_point.xml**:

```
<Page xmlns:sd="nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer" xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatedTo="onNavigatedTo">

    <ActionBar title="Geminid Systems" class="action-bar">
        <ActionItem tap="toggleDrawer" ios.systemIcon="4" android.systemIcon="ic_menu_btn_add" ios.position="left" />
    </ActionBar>

    <sd:RadSideDrawer id="sideDrawer" drawerLocation="Left">
        <sd:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent>
          <StackLayout class="sidedrawer-left">
             <StackLayout class="sidedrawer-header">
               <Label text="Geminid Systems" class="sidedrawer-header-brand" />
             </StackLayout>
             <StackLayout class="sidedrawer-content hamburgerMenu">
               <Label text="Home" class="sidedrawer-list-item-text" />
               <Label text="Accounts" class="sidedrawer-list-item-text" />
               <Label text="Calendar" class="sidedrawer-list-item-text" />
               <Label text="Activity" class="sidedrawer-list-item-text" />
               <Label text="Advanced" class="sidedrawer-list-item-text" />
               <Label text="Online " class="sidedrawer-list-item-text" />
            </StackLayout>
         </StackLayout>

         </sd:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent>

         <sd:RadSideDrawer.mainContent>
            <StackLayout>    
                <Button text="Toggle Drawer" class="btn" tap="toggleDrawer" />

            </StackLayout>
         </sd:RadSideDrawer.mainContent>
    </sd:RadSideDrawer>

</Page>
```

**starting_point.js**:

```
var drawer;

exports.toggleDrawer = function () {
  drawer.showDrawer();
};
exports.onNavigatedTo = function (args) {
  var page = args.object;
  drawer = page.getViewById("sideDrawer");
};
```

And this works absolutely fine.  
The problem occurs when I try to modularise and move the side-drawer code to a `shared` folder so that I do not have to repeat the code over and over again in all pages where I'd require a side-drawer.
So I did it like this:

Project Structure:

```
.
├── app 
|   └── shared
|       └── sidedrawer.xml
|       └── sidedrawer.js
|   ├── app.css
|   ├── app.js
|   ├── starting_point.xml
```

**starting_point.xml**:

```xml
<Page xmlns:sd="nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer" xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatedTo="onNavigatedTo">

    <ActionBar title="Geminid Systems" class="action-bar">
        <ActionItem tap="toggleDrawer" ios.systemIcon="4" android.systemIcon="ic_menu_btn_add" ios.position="left" />
    </ActionBar>

    <sd:RadSideDrawer id="sideDrawer" drawerLocation="Left">
        <sd:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent>

               <shared:sidedrawer /> <!-- CHANGE - Moved the content inside RadSideDrawer.drawerContent to shared/sidedrawer.xml for reusability and removed JS code from starting_point.js and put it in shared/sidedrawer.js -->

        </sd:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent>

        <sd:RadSideDrawer.mainContent>
            <StackLayout>    
                <Button text="Toggle Drawer" class="btn" tap="toggleDrawer" />

            </StackLayout>
        </sd:RadSideDrawer.mainContent>
    </sd:RadSideDrawer>
</Page>
```

**shared/sidedrawer.xml**

```
<StackLayout class="sidedrawer-left">
  <StackLayout class="sidedrawer-header">
    <Label text="Geminid Systems" class="sidedrawer-header-brand" />
  </StackLayout>
  <StackLayout class="sidedrawer-content hamburgerMenu">
    <Label text="Home" class="sidedrawer-list-item-text" />
    <Label text="Accounts" class="sidedrawer-list-item-text" />
    <Label text="Calendar" class="sidedrawer-list-item-text" />
    <Label text="Activity" class="sidedrawer-list-item-text" />
    <Label text="Advanced" class="sidedrawer-list-item-text" />
    <Label text="Online " class="sidedrawer-list-item-text" />
  </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

**shared/sidedrawer.js**:

```
// no changes - same as the previous starting_point.js
var drawer;

exports.toggleDrawer = function () {
  drawer.showDrawer();
};
exports.onNavigatedTo = function (args) {
  var page = args.object;
  drawer = page.getViewById("sideDrawer");
};
```

This is the error I'm getting :

```
System.err: Error: Building UI from XML. @file:///app/views/home/home.xml:9:7
System.err: Module 'ui/sidedrawer' not found for element 'Sidedrawer'.
System.err: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "ui/sidedrawer", relative to: app/tns_modules/
System.err: com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:146)
```

I'm a complete beginner and any suggestions would help!
Thanks.

Comment: Could you post file `app/views/home/home.xml` contents?

Comment: Oh when I wrote this question, I changed the name of `home.xml` to `starting_point.xml` for clarity purposes.
So the error log should in fact read `System.err: Error: Building UI from XML. @file:///app/views/starting_point/starting_point.xml:9:7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the section Custom Components in [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/basics) you can see a custom namespace added to `Page`, and that is what you need to do.

On `starting_point.xml` add `xmlns:shared="path/to/shared.xml"` (with your correct path).